# how can I use NSURLConnection Asynchronously?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am using this code to load data to my App, can you tell me how can I make this asynchronously?

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request2 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];


NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request2 delegate:self];
if (connection)
{
    NSLog(@"NSURLConnection connection==true");
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request2 returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    self.news =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:nil error:nil];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", self.news);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"NSURLConnection connection==false");
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block code is your friend. I have created a class which does this for you

Objective-C Block code. Create this class here

Interface class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "WebCall.h"

@interface WebCall : NSObject
{
    void(^webCallDidFinish)(NSString *response);

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *responseData;

-(void)setWebCallDidFinish:(void (^)(NSString *))wcdf;

-(void)webServiceCall :(NSString *)sURL_p : (NSMutableArray *)valueList_p : (NSMutableArray *)keyList_p;

@end
```

Implementation class

```
#import "WebCall.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation WebCall

@synthesize responseData;

-(void)setWebCallDidFinish:(void (^)(NSString *))wcdf
{
    webCallDidFinish = [wcdf copy];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    int responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];

    NSLog(@"Response Code = %i", responseStatusCode);
    if(responseStatusCode < 200 || responseStatusCode > 300)
    {
        webCallDidFinish(@"failure");
    }



    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{

    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [responseData appendData:data]; 
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    NSLog(@"WebCall Error: %@", error);
    webCallDidFinish(@"failure");
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

        NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        response = [response stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        webCallDidFinish(response);

}

-(void)webServiceCall :(NSString *)sURL_p : (NSMutableArray *)valueList_p : (NSMutableArray *)keyList_p
{
    NSMutableString *sPost = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    //If any variables need passed in - append them to the POST
    //E.g. if keyList object is username and valueList object is adam will append like
    //http://test.jsp?username=adam
    if([valueList_p count] > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < [valueList_p count]; i++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                    [sPost appendFormat:@"%@=%@", [valueList_p objectAtIndex:i],[keyList_p objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
            else
            {

                    [sPost appendFormat:@"&%@=%@", [valueList_p objectAtIndex:i], [keyList_p objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
        }
    }


    NSData * postData = [sPost dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
    NSString * postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];



    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL_p];
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:5];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    if (theConnection)
    {
        self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
    }


}

@end
```

Then you to make this web call, you call it like this

```
     WebCall *webCall = [[WebCall alloc] init];


        [webCall setWebCallDidFinish:^(NSString *response){

            //This method is called as as soon as the web call is finished

NSString *trimmedString = [response stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                   [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        if([trimmedString rangeOfString:@"failure"].location == NSNotFound)
        {
           //Successful web call
        }
        else
        {
           //If the webcall failed due to an error
        }

        }];


        //Make web call here
        [webCall webServiceCall:@"http://www.bbc.co.uk/" :nil :nil];
```

See the setWebCallDidFinish method, it will not be called until the webcall has finished.

Hope that helps!!

Comment: thanks for code, I used this code for fetching json but I've got error when use this line in setWebCallDidFinish methos:
 NSArray *test=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:trimmedString options:nil error:nil];

Comment: trimmedString is of type String, that JSON serialization method is expecting an  NSData object to be passed in. The example code I supplied returns a String, if you want you can modify the code to return an NSdata Object instead

Answer (score 4):

I think you should be bothered reading the documentation. There's a [`sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-SW10) method.

Comment: I already read that, not sure what to pass to queue or completionHandler, just needed example code

Answer (score 2):

Create the connection with `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:`, set yourself as its delegate and implement the delegate methods.

Comment: Note that this method is now obsolescent in favor of the block-based `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` message.

Comment: @H2CO3 I disagree -  and this is not true. This is a "convenience" method - which can be used when it "works". Usually it works only in samples, toy programs, code snippets to demonstrate some other things, etc. It had been even the case that the asynchronous convenient method was a wrapper around the synchronous convenient method.  Seriously, use the delegates.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [HTTPCachedController](https://github.com/vamitrou/HTTPCachedController)

It will help you send POST and GET requests, while it will cache the response and after that it will return the cached data when no internet connection is available.

```
HTTPCachedController *ctrl = [[[HTTPCachedController alloc] initWithRequestType:1 andDelegate:self] autorelease];
[ctrl getRequestToURL:@"https://api.github.com/orgs/twitter/repos?page=1&per_page=10"];
```

You will get notified when the data are fetched through a delegate method:

```
-(void)connectionFinishedWithData:(NSString*)data andRequestType:(int)reqType
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code which I am using in my app:

```
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourURL]];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                                   if (error) {
                                       NSLog(@"Error loading data from %@. Error Userinfo: %@",yourURL, [error userInfo]);
                                   } else {
                                   NSDictionary *dataFromServer = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
                                   contentAsString = [[[dataFromServer objectForKey:@"page"] objectForKey:@"content"] stripHtml];
                                   completionHandler(contentAsString);
                               }];
```

fyi: stripHTML is a NSString Category to remove HTML tags from JSON --> [Found it Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7341993/2207018)

you can call your content in your class like that:

```
[yourClass getDataWithcompletionHandler:^(NSString *content) {
    yourObject.content = content;
    [yourClass saveManagedObjectContext];
}];
```

if you implement it once, you won't want to use synchronous connection again...

Comment: Thanks for sample code, I didn't understand the second part, can you explain what is getDataWithcompletionHandler for? and when can I use it?

Comment: by using the completion handler you make sure that in this case the string has the content from your connection, as the code in the completion handler is only executed after the connection successfully terminated. As the sendAsynchronousRequest is executed in another thread than your mainthread, it could happen, that your program runs faster than your connection and your data (or string here) would be nil because your device didn't get an response from the server yet. So you use the completion handler to assign the value to the objects in the completion block. I use it where I declare and

Comment: save my objects in Core Data.  sendAsynchronousRequest is still faster than a synchronous request, because it doesn't stop the rest of your program from being executed and nothing (exept the code in the completion block) waits for the request to be finished.  Especially your UI flow isn't interrupted by the request.